# Javascript: Remove images before browser requests them possible on page loading?

Tags: javascript

```
    var imgs=document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for(i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
        console.log(imgs[i]);
        if(typeof imgs[i]!='undefined' && typeof imgs[i].parentNode!='undefined') {
            (imgs[i].parentNode).removeChild(imgs[i]);
        }
    }
```

I have tried to remove images before page actually loads, but images are loaded on background anyway.

Abort them anyhow.

Comment: Try adding imgs[i]=null after removing it and imgs=null after the loop to clean up any references, still I don't know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work because most browsers will try to fetch the image while the HTML is read. You would have to do this server-side. Something like

```
<img data-src="..."/>
```

And then use javascript to set src when you want to actually load it.

Comment: Yes, preferably `data-src` or similar attribute.

Comment: Too bad :( I would like to do some client-side refactoring only. Would be cool if browsers allow to manipulate document before rendering it.

Comment: @Beck Look at this plugin. Maybe it will help you http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: Although for me it never worked. I think it all depends on your browser.

Comment: Guess i'll have to refactor serverside templates then. Ty again. I'll accept the topic tomorrow.