# jquery remove images from page before they get loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

My problem is simmilar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835957/javascript-remove-images-before-browser-requests-them-possible-on-page-loading) but I can't do it server side, since I only want to remove the images *if* the browser width is less than 850px.
I am currently using this:

```
$(function () {
    if($(document).width() < 850) {
        $('.thumb').remove();
    }
});
```

The images get removed, but as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28aJJ.png), the browser loads them anyway.
Do anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks

**Solution (it works now!:**

Instead of always loading the images, never load them, unless the browser is greater than 850
HTML:

```
<?php 
if(file_exists($sites[$i].'/thumb.png')) { ?>
    <img class="thumb" data="/experiments/<?=$sites[$i]?>/thumb.png" />
<?php 
} 
?>
```

JS:

```
$('.thumb').each(function(index, element) {

        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('data'));
});
```

Comment: but WHY? Is there a good reason for this?

Comment: I don't want the mobile device to load the thumbnails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to turn it the other way around: Meaning that you'll only load images if the doc. width is wider then 850. As far as I know the images will be requested / loaded before the script runs if they're "hard coded" in the HTML document.

Comment: so.. something like data-src and then .replace() ??

Comment: I just don't want a lot of javascript to happen, so the document loads faster, in the first way, it's the greater monitors who work, while the other way it's the small ones, e.g. phones

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm thinking. However I don't think replace() is nessecary as using attr("src") will replace it regardless.

Comment: Regarding your second comment. You will have to make an decision on what's the lesser evil. Higher bandwith or JavaScript performance requirements. I would say that using the least ammount of bandwith is more important for a mobile solution as most smart phones these days can handle heavy JavaScript execution just fine.

Comment: Yes, I belive that would work. I've never tried doing this client side , but it's an interesting experiment.

Comment: hmm there's some problems now, can you figure out what's wrong? http://jonas.xn--rssum-vua.dk/ they get an src, but it doesnt put the data-src in it

Comment: @KGChristensen Can you post a JSFiddle of this in action?

Comment: Given that I'd found the right element, you should see the issue. You're using the wrong attribute :)
<img class="thumb" data-src="/experiments/ballwar/thumb.png" src="">
I think this is a simple syntax error, if you post your updated code we should be able to find it.

Comment: var src = element.attr('data-src'); should be just ('src') given that element is an image.

Comment: oh, i see, is it then dataSrc?

Comment: It gives undefined with element.src = element.data

Comment: What kind of object is element? Is it an image? This is the general syntax for replacing / adding image src,
 $('#someImage').attr('src', http://i.imgur.com/IL6AO.png');

Comment: Okay, think we got it now! $(element) instead of element!

Comment: Thank you KG, you are a very nice person :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21876/discussion-between-dremp-and-kg-christensen)

Answer (score 0):

Of course.
Remove() first loads them, then removes them from the DOM.

The only way to remove them so that the browser never loads them is with a server-side language. In the server side language, you could detect if the picture is on the page and if it is, you could remove them. And therefore the image is never sent to the browser.

As for your case, "if($(document).width() < 850)" is used, so you can't do all of it server side.

Why don't you just interchange between server-side and browser-side? Like PHP and JavaScript?

For example, you could, with JavaScript detect if the document width is less then 850. If it is, it loads an iframe with the parameter (remove=true). The iframe page would have all the .thumb and images and all the content, and you could use PHP on the page to detect if the "remove=true" parameter was present (use $_GET[remove]). If it was, it would not display the .thumb and never send it to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

KG Christensen's and your idea of setting the image's `src` attribute is good.

Another idea which could work is to have the images with a `display: none;` style, and change it to `display: inline;` only if your condition is met. The browsers shouldn't load the images if they're hidden.

Something along the lines of:

```
<style type="text/css">
.thumb {
  display: none;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(document).width() >= 850)
    $('.thumb').show();
});
</script>
```

Comment: That could work too, didn't know about that. It makes me think about the youtube player in tweets, if you close the tweet, it stops playing, so i wondered if it removed it with javascript or css

Comment: It doesn't seem to work: 
http://i.imgur.com/LNQJJ.png http://i.imgur.com/YC5mI.png

Comment: Hmm, I tested your suggestion @orip, but from what I'm seeing that image is loaded even though it's set to display: none; initally.